# Check if color is already in array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am working on a Java program that is making an array of colors that have been used in another array to draw a picture. I am stumbling on writing code that creates this new array, while also excluding colors that have been added to this array already.

I would appreciate any help into where I am going wrong with my code.

Thanks. My code is below:

```
public ArrayList<Color> getColorList()
{
    ArrayList<Color> getColorList;
    getColorList = new ArrayList<Color>();
    int index = 0;
    boolean colorAdded = false;
    for(Stroke stroke : drawing){
        while(index <= getColorList.size() && colorAdded == false) {
        if(getColorList.get(index) == stroke.getColor()){
            colorAdded = true;
        }
        else{
            index = index + 1;
        }
    }
    if(colorAdded == false){
            getColorList.add(stroke.getColor());
        }
    index = 0;
    colorAdded = false;
    }
    return getColorList();
}
```

Comment: Use a set. That has duplicate prevention built in.

Comment: A recursive method that always initializes a list with the same name that the method? Dude, you really need to take programming lessons.

Comment: Don't use `==` to test for object equality. Use `equals` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the colors in a Set and you dont need to worry about duplication:

```
Set<Color> distinctColors = new HashSet<Color>();
distinctColors .add(stroke.getColor());

return new ArrayList<Color>(distinctColors );
```

Above code will return an arraylist of distinct colors.

EDIT[After comments]:

Color class should implement hashcode and equals methods such that if 2 objects are equal then they have same hashcode and if 2 objects have same hashcode then they may or may not be equal.

Comment: You need to add that when using a `Set` the class must implement `hashCode` and `equals` methods, otherwise it will behave as `List`.

Comment: Thanks for the input - it's much appreciated.
@LuiggiMendoza when you said I was using a recursive method that always initializes a list with the same name as the method, was that in reference to for(Stroke stroke : drawing)?

Comment: @user2229659 in your method, you return `getColorList()` (note the parenthesis usage).

Comment: Could someone please point out where I have gone wrong in my original script. I am currently in a intro programming course and so the 'set' solution is not how I am supposed to be tackling the problem.
Cheers